# Pandas to sum unique values, and into a table

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to figure out how to built a table in pandas, having pandas count unique values, retreived from an excel sheet.

table:

```
|--------------|--------------------|
|  location    |   signal           |
|--------------|--------------------|
|  New York    |  Vehicle 20 open   |
|  New York    |  Vehicle 22 open   |
|  Washington  |  Vehicle 20 open   |
|  Washington  |  Vehicle 21 open   |
|  New York    |  Vehicle 20 open   |
|  New York    |  Vehicle 22 open   |
|  Washington  |  Vehicle 20 open   |
|  Washington  |  Vehicle 21 open   |
|  New York    |  Vehicle 20 open   |
|  New York    |  Vehicle 22 open   |
|  Washington  |  Vehicle 20 closed |
|  Washington  |  Vehicle 21 closed |
|  New York    |  Vehicle 20 closed |
|  New York    |  Vehicle 22 closed |
|  Washington  |  Vehicle 20 closed |
|  Washington  |  Vehicle 21 closed |
|  New York    |  Vehicle 20 open   |
|  New York    |  Vehicle 20 open   |
|  New York    |  Vehicle 20 open   |
|--------------|--------------------|
```

How I wan't it to be printed out (And exported into Excel)

```
|--------------|-------------------|------------------|
|  Alarmtype   |   Vehicle open    |  Vehicle Closed  | 
|--------------|-------------------|------------------|
|  New York    |      9            |      2           |
|  Washington  |      4            |      4           |
|--------------|-------------------|------------------|
```

So I want to count the amount of times each event(group) happens within each location, and some them up into a table

This is what I have tried

```py
top = df.groupby(['Location', 'Sign Descr']).count()

or

sorted = df.sort_values(["Location", "Sign Descr"]).groupby(['Location', 'Sign Descr']).nunique()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another one with [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
pd.crosstab(df.location,df.signal.str.replace('\d+',''))
```

---

```
signal      Vehicle  closed  Vehicle  open
location                                  
New York                  2              9
Washington                4              4
```

Answer (score 4):

First replace the numbers in your `signal` column, then use [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df['signal'] = df['signal'].str.replace('([0-9])', '')

pd.pivot_table(df, index='location', columns='signal', aggfunc='size')
```

---

```
signal      Vehicle  closed  Vehicle  open
location                                  
New York                  2              9
Washington                4              4
```

---

If you want `Alarmtype` as index name. Add `rename_axis`:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index='location', columns='signal', aggfunc='size').rename_axis('Alarmtype')
```

```
signal      Vehicle  closed  Vehicle  open
Alarmtype                                 
New York                  2              9
Washington                4              4
```

Comment: and if you don't want to use the original data, use a different column..

Comment: Wow, that was fast :)
I changed the column and index
pd.pivot_table(df, index='signal', columns='location', aggfunc='size')

is it possible to remove the NaN or replace by 0?

Comment: Question. How do you copy the OPs example into your session?

Comment: This case I had to remove the `|` and `-` manually with ctrl-f & replace. But normally just copy the data to your clipboard and use `df = pd.read_clipboard('\s\s+')` @Sotos

Comment: `NaN` should not be included since`dropna=True` by default in `pivot_table`. But if you want to replace NaN with zero use: `pd.pivot_table(df.fillna(0), index='location', columns='signal', aggfunc='size')`

Answer (score 0):

You can have the same with the **groupby** and **pivot** as well. To try this, please find the code below

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('c.csv')
print(data)



grp_data = data.groupby(by=['location','status']).count().reset_index()
print(grp_data)
grp_data.pivot(index='location',columns='status',values=['signal'])
```

**Original Data:**

```
      location  signal  status
0     New York      20    open
1     New York      22    open
2   Washington      20    open
3   Washington      21    open
4     New York      20    open
5     New York      22    open
6   Washington      20    open
7   Washington      21    open
8     New York      20    open
9     New York      22    open
10  Washington      20  closed
11  Washington      21  closed
12    New York      20  closed
13    New York      22  closed
14  Washington      20  closed
15  Washington      21  closed
16    New York      20    open
17    New York      20    open
18    New York      20    open
```

**Group By Output:**

```
     location  status  signal
0    New York  closed       2
1    New York    open       9
2  Washington  closed       4
3  Washington    open       4
```

**Final Output:**

```
           signal
status  closed  open
location        
New York    2   9
Washington  4   4
```